# Undefined Javascript variable - phcat

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that returns an undefined variable. I tried all responses in some similar posts but no results.

`identifier_id` is defined but `phcat` is not defined. Any ideas?

```
$(function() {
  $('body').on('click', '.save_random_profile', function() {
    var identifier_id = $(this).attr("id");
    $('.created_profile' + identifier_id).html('<img src="img/loader.gif" class="loading" />'); 
     var phcat =  document.getElementById('#phcat'+identifier_id).value; 
    alert(phcat);

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      async: false,
      url: "actions/save_random_profile.php",
      data: dataString,
      cache: false,
      success: function(data) {
        if (data == 0) {
          $('.created_profile' + identifier_id).html('Not Sent!');
        } else {
          $('.created_profile' + identifier_id).html(data);
        }
      }  
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: What's the point of getting the `id` of an element you selected by it's `id` - you already have that value in `identifier_id`. The problem itself is because jQuery objects don't have an `id` property. You need to use `.prop('id')` instead - although as I stated before, this is entirely redundant code.

Comment: var phcat = $('.phcat#' + identifier_id).id; to var phcat = $('.phcat#' + identifier_id).attr('id');

Comment: change to `var phcat = $('.phcat#' + identifier_id).id;` and check  . but what is `.id` here? i think it need to be `.val()` or `.text()` or `attr('id')` .. something like that

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan if you look carefully, i get a value wich is stored as an id for an object like an input form. Each input form has an unique id wich is equal with label+unique_identifier. Each id's value will be stored as variables and then posted to a php script.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, sorry, i made a mistake in my code. Now it is updated!

Comment: Given your update the problem is because you put a `#` in the id you give to getElementById. You just need to remove that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`jquery.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

`Object.id` is a native javascript method and will not be applicable on a jquery collection objects.

To get the id in a jquery object, use `var phcat = $('.phcat#' + identifier_id).attr("id");`

Or if you want to persist with javascript, use `document.querySelector('.phcat#' + identifier_id).id;`

```
$(function() {
  $('body').on('click', '.save_random_profile', function() {
    var identifier_id = $(this).attr("id");
    $('.created_profile' + identifier_id).html('<img src="img/loader.gif" class="loading" />'); 
    var phcat = $('.phcat#' + identifier_id).attr("id");
    alert(phcat);

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      async: false,
      url: "actions/save_random_profile.php",
      data: dataString,
      cache: false,
      success: function(data) {
        if (data == 0) {
          $('.created_profile' + identifier_id).html('Not Sent!');
        } else {
          $('.created_profile' + identifier_id).html(data);
        }
      }  
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

**EDIT**

If you are using `document.getElementById`, do not use the `#` along with the id.

```
var phcat =  document.getElementById('phcat'+identifier_id).value;
```

Comment: Sorry, i made a mistake in my code. Now it is updated!

Answer (score 0):

Use `var phcat =  $('.phcat#'+identifier_id).attr('id');`

Comment: please explain your answer

Comment: Sorry, i made a mistake in my code. Now it is updated!

Answer (score 0):

use

> var phcat = $('.phcat#' + identifier_id)[0].id;

it will give you native JS obj

OR

```
var phcat = $('.phcat#' + identifier_id).attr('id');
```

it will return id of element